# Differentiate between owned and linked notes for evernote business account on production

Tags: java, evernote

I am trying to sync entire evernote account to my server(all notes and tags) but I am not able to distinguish between owned and linked notes for Business accounts, as the shards are same for all the notes in a business account. So whenever I authenticate to that particular shard I am able to access all the notes irrespective of ownership. *I want to sync only owned business notes for a user*. 
Also the note attributes **author and creatorId** does not provide a reliable and consistent information to separate out notes.

Thanks